# mysql erroneous query

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a a problem here, i have this query:

```
function getPrelaciones($carnet){
  $result = query(
      "SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 
       FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm
       , Materia m
       , (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista 
          FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha 
          WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '11111') as n 
       WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo 
       AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != '' 
       AND n.materianovista = m.codigo");

  print json_encode($result);
}
```

and it works, but when i try to make it general, switching the `'11111'` for `$carnet` like the next query, it doesnt work, well it works but it returns a empty json:

```
function getPrelaciones($carnet){
  $result = query(
      "SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 
      FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm 
      , Materia m
      , (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista 
         FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha 
         WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '%s' ) as n 
      WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo 
      AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != '' 
      AND n.materianovista = m.codigo", $carnet);
  print json_encode($result);
}
```

any solution?, thanks

my query function look like this:

```
function query() {
global $link;
$debug = false;

//get the sql query
$args = func_get_args();
$sql = array_shift($args);

//secure the input
for ($i=0;$i<count($args);$i++) {
    $args[$i] = urldecode($args[$i]);
    $args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
}

//build the final query
$sql = vsprintf($sql, $args);

if ($debug) print $sql;

//execute and fetch the results
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if (mysqli_errno($link)==0 && $result) {

    $rows = array();

    if ($result!==true)
    while ($d = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        array_push($rows,$d);
    }

    //return json
    return array('result'=>$rows);

} else {

    //error
    return array('error'=>'Database error');
}
}
```

Comment: What does your `query` function look like?

Comment: Change `mha.Alumno_carnet = '%s'` with `mha.Alumno_carnet like '%s'`

Comment: @Meherzad I think that `%s` is a string identifier like in `printf` and in that case he should assign a value to it.

Comment: i am trying to do that using $carnet at the ent of the query but it does not work i get a empty json

Comment: What does `echo $sql` print? (just before calling `mysqli_query`)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, basic debugging. Change this:

```
$debug = false;
```

... into this:

```
$debug = true;
```

You'll see what your SQL contains.

My educated guess if that you've not enabled full error reporting and you've forgotten to initialise `$link` so you're at (not) seeing this warning:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli,
>   null given

... on this line:

```
$args[$i] = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $args[$i]);
```

When [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) fails it returns `NULL`, thus then displaying your SQL query you get this:

```
WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = ''
                          ^^
```

Side notes:

1. You're using a modern library that supports prepared statements. Why care fiddling with escaping?
2. What exactly do you think `urldecode()` does? What does the `url` prefix suggest?

Answer (score -1):

I think it will be simplier just to add your variable to the sql in `getPrelaciones`, and not send it to the function

like this:

```
function getPrelaciones($carnet){
  $result = query("SELECT mhm.Materia_codigo1 FROM Materia_has_Materia mhm, Materia m, (SELECT mha.Materia_codigo as materianovista FROM Materia_has_Alumno mha WHERE mha.Alumno_carnet = '".$carnet."')as n WHERE n.materianovista = mhm.Materia_codigo AND mhm.Materia_codigo1 != '' AND n.materianovista = m.codigo");
  print json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, because SQL Injection is just a myth.